# START /B with php/node/python script doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, windows, shell, batch-file, command-line

I start a shell and I run the following command:

```
START "" /B php test.php>nul 2>&1
```

For the purposes of this post, test.php consists of 1 line: file_put_contents("test", "test");

You'd expect it to instantly create a file called test, however it doesn't.
Instead, when I enter the command and hit enter, nothing happens. However, in the same command window, if I hit the enter key once more, the script will run.

I've tried the equivalent command with node, python2 and python3. They all do the same thing, although python3 oiddly enough requires 2 enter key presses before the script is run.

This appears to be a quirk when running START /B with script interpreters. If I ran START /B with an .exe or .bat then it runs as expected.

Now, obviously I don't need to run a background process that creates a file named 'test'. What I need it to do is to start a daemon process written in php and a daemon process written in nodejs, one after the other in the same terminal.

I've also noticed if I write these commands to a batch file and run them by double clicking the batch file instead of calling it from the shell, then it all runs as expected.

Please help. I've been wrestling with this problem for 2 days now.

EDIT:

I've just found that this problem is unique to my computer, running on Windows 10. I tried on Windows 7 and Windows XP and they did not require extra return inputs from me to run the script...

I've just tried booting up in safe mode and clearing my path variables. Still it persists.
I wonder if this is a bug/feature of Windows 10?
How the hell do I diagnose and fix this?

EDIT 2:

Just tested the same script on a Windows 8 machine, which unexpectedly does exactly what my Windows 10 machine does. SO it looks like only Windows 8 and Windows 10 have this problem... And using legacy mode makes no difference.
What the FFFFFFFFFnnngggghhhrrr... I can't find anyone reporting this issue anywhere.

Here's a gif animation of exactly what happens:

[image]

Proof that the script is only run on the second return key press.

Comment: What does it do if you remove `>nul 2>&1`?

Comment: It's definitely something to do with the `>nul 2>&1`. I think the first `>nul` is not escaped properly

Comment: Nope, tried that. Try entering it directly into the console yourself and you should experience the same unusual behaviour: START "" /B php test.php>nul 2>&1 won't run on the first return.

Comment: I've modified my post, looks like it's unique to me, still no closer to fixing it though... Help me please.

Comment: OK, just realised the problem is not unique to me, but to Windows 8 and 10 OS's. Completely flummoxed...

Comment: @Mofi Tried it. Didn't work. If anyone has PHP and Windows 8/10 please try it.

Comment: Missing `?>` denoting end of `test.php` script?

Comment: Tried it. Still goes wrong! Can somebody with a Windows 8/10 machine please demonstrate that it is indeed a problem they can see themselves? It is utterly maddening to not find anyone else running into the same problem, yet I've tested this on many machines and found it to be a trait of seemingly all Windows 8 and 10 OS's.

Comment: Try: `START "" /B php test.php^>nul 2^>^&1`

Comment: @hedgehog90 Maybe it's none of my business, but why use `>NUL 2>&1` anyway?  If you simply comment out all `echo` statements in your PHP file, then `>NUL` is already redirecting nothing.  And is there a reason you'd want to redirect stderr to stdout?

Comment: @rojo >NUL 2>&1 is not required, in my GIF example you'll see I don't use it. It makes no difference to the result. However, when used with a socket listener php script it allows me to enter commands afterwards, without it the command prompt stalls at the php script.

Comment: @Aacini when I run `START "" /B php test.php^>nul 2^>^&1` I get: 'Could not open input file: test.php>nul' If I run this however: `START "" /B php test.php 1^>nul 2^>^&1` it runs... but guess what? ... still requires an extra return... this is getting a bit tiresome isn't it?

Comment: All these responses and not a single one works... Should I take this to Windows? Where can I go to submit a bug? As I've said previously, this works perfectly with a Windows 7 and prior. The issue appears to only affect Windows 8 and 10 only. Again I would **LOVE** it if someone could test it themselves and confirm this... I find it hard to believe that this problem I'm experiencing with php/python script executions from the START /B command has not affected anyone since Windows 8's release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `<NUL` to send an additional <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the command.

```
start "" /b php test.php <NUL
```

Re: *why* this happens, sorry, I couldn't answer that part.  Bug?  Security?  Undocumented feature?  *shrug*

Comment: I'm afraid this runs exactly the same as before. Still requires I press return on the following empty command

Comment: @hedgehog90 See my edit.  We'll trial and error this thing.  :)

Comment: <NUL WORKED! Thank you! ... buuuuut, I need to find out why this happens.

Comment: I just gave you the 50 rep points, I doubt we'll get to the bottom of why without asking Microsoft directly. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`start /b` starts another process, which shares Input and Output with the original Windows. (to verify do `start /b "" prompt $G` and press Return repeatedly)

Better start the secondary process in another Windows (no `/b` - use `/min` instead to run it minimized). You also should give it an `Exit`, else it keeps open:

```
start /min "" echo hello^>hello.txt^&Exit
```

Note: if you don't escape special chars like `>`, `&`, `|`,..., they will be processed by "start" - in other words, in your original context, not in the newly started process.

Comment: Problem is the php script I actually want to run is a socket listener, that extra CMD window will need to stay open. I think I said in my OP that I also need an instance of a node script running as well, so that would make 3 CMD windows in total.

Comment: well, then forget the `exit`. The point is to run the script in it's own window - no "shared input" (I don't have php, but I'm quite sure that's not the problem. It's the "shared input" that works - well - weird)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem here.
Perhaps you corrupted your cmd.exe with some of your tests.
For the tests I opened a new cmd window

I tested with

#### test.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

And

```
start "myTitle" /b php test.php
```

Comment: Which OS are you running? I only have the issue on Windows 8 and 10

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem and stumbled on this SO question while trying to find an answer.

In my case I was trying to run a windows command from PHP using 'popen'.
I had recently upgraded Wampserver as well as Windows 10 from 8.
My code worked prior to the upgrade and subsequently was timing out.
I found the same issue on command line as well - having to input newlines to receive output.

My solution was two fold:
1. On the command line I found that adding the '/wait' switch fixed that.
2. The shell used by PHP had a different PATH to that of the cmd shell. My path to php.exe was defined twice, there was an old entry for my old version of Wampserver. So I removed it. Note I had to restart PC for the path to update correctly.