# Running .Net Core Application from batch script and redirecting exception

Tags: c#, batch-file, .net-core, io-redirection

NET Core Console App` from a batch script and redirect the exceptions to a file.I am also providing arguments to this script:

My script so far:

```
rem **calling C# solution from batch*******
@echo received from python param1:%1 , param2:%2 ,param3:%3
start "Dotnet Test" D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll  dotnet %1 %2 %3 2>output.txt
pause
```

**.NET Core Console App**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            if (!File.Exists(args[0])) {
                File.Create(args[0]);
            }


            if(double.TryParse(args[1],out double dbl)) {
                Console.WriteLine($"arg[1]={dbl.ToString()}");
            }
            if (int.TryParse(args[2], out int inte)) {
                Console.WriteLine($"arg[2]={inte.ToString()}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

So far i tried with `2>` for redirecting exception but it creates a `0kb` file.

***P.S*** Also i am not sure if i am correctly running the `.Net Core Application`.I have used:
Source: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html
`START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]` ,
In our case where does `dotnet` command fit in? You normally start from terminal with 
`dotnet [appname].dll` but here you place it after the path and the `dll` name?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `|` or `>>` instead of `>`?

Comment: `>` and `>>` are pretty similar i didn't want to append.

Comment: Ah, okay, my bad.

Comment: I'm suprised that you can run a `.dll` with the `start` command, `.dll`'s aren't really executable files, they're usually passed as arguments to another exectutable, which in turn runs it.

Comment: Well that is how i understand you run `.NET Core applicaitons` using `dotnet [name of dll]`.

Comment: It appears that you used `[name of dll] dotnet` instead. Do parameters need to be preceded by `--`?

Comment: I actually used `dotnet` in the snippet but it is in the position according to my link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In our case where does dotnet command fit in? You normally start from terminal with
>   dotnet [appname].dll but here you place it after the path and the dll name?

Apart from other problems,

`start "Dotnet Test" D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll  dotnet %1 %2 %3 2>output.txt`

should be

`start "Dotnet Test" dotnet D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll %1 %2 %3 2>output.txt`

You cannot run a DLL, you want to run dotnet to execute the code contained in the DLL.

> Also i am not sure if i am correctly running the .Net Core Application.

I suspect you are trying to use *start* because of the misunderstanding described above. To run your app in the script, all you need is:

`dotnet D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll %1 %2 %3 2>output.txt`

You only need *start* when you want to run your .NET Core app in a separate window, parallel to the rest of the script. This is what the command

`start "Dotnet Test" dotnet D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll %1 %2 %3 2^>output.txt`

should do. I'm writing *should* because it *should* work according to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182529/8656352) but actually it won't.

I could make it work only using a workaround. I created a separate batch script *runapp.cmd* with the following content:

`dotnet [appname].dll %1 %2 %3 2>error.txt & exit`

And had *start* call this script:

`start "Dotnet Test" runapp.cmd %1 %2 %3`

Comment: I supplied the arguments in the order provided by the link ,or what i thought the link said.I myself wasn't sure if `dotnet` should be near the end but in that pattern isn't it in the place of "command"?

Comment: In your snippet `D:\adi\NET\Bench\Bench\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Bench.dll` is in the place of "command".

Comment: getting error: `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in '.....path....'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the ....path.....runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.`